# Need to convert a query from Redshift to Presto

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, presto

Given below query written in AWS Redhift:

```
SELECT session_date,'min' as stats,mini as value,product,endpoint
from 
(select 
distinct trunc(joinstart_ev_timestamp) as session_date, 
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.02) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY join_time) over(partition by 
trunc(joinstart_ev_timestamp))/1000 as mini,
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY join_time) OVER (partition by         
trunc(joinstart_ev_timestamp))/1000 as first_quartile,
median(join_time) over(partition by trunc(joinstart_ev_timestamp))/1000 as 
jt,
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY join_time) OVER (partition by 
trunc(joinstart_ev_timestamp))/1000 as third_quartile,
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.98) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY join_time) over(partition by 
trunc(joinstart_ev_timestamp))/1000 as maxi,
product_name as product,
endpoint as endpoint
from qe_datawarehouse.join_session_fact
where  
trunc(joinstart_ev_timestamp)  between '2018-01-18' and '2018-01-30'
and lower(product_name) LIKE 'gotowebinar%' 
and join_time>0 and join_time <= 600000 and join_time is not null 
and audio_connect_time >= 0  
and (entrypoint_access_time >= 0 or entrypoint_access_time is null)
and (panel_connect_time >= 0  or panel_connect_time is null) and version = 
'V2');
```

I need to convert it into corresponding Presto query.

I have tried below:

- When I am running above Hive query in Presto as it is then I am getting error:
  " Query failed (#20180212_044343_00014_jb834): line 5:36: missing 'BY' at '(' "
- I know that I have to use "approx_percentile()" in presto somehow but not actually able to use it.

NOTE: 
In Redshift query, every column is considered as String but in Presto, the data types are shown below:

```
create external table if not exists join_session_fact (
 join_session_fact_id string
,session_tracking_id string
,user_id string
,participant_id string
,meeting_id string
,session_mcs_id string
,browser_name string
,browser_version string
,endpoint string
,entrypoint string
,build_number string
,model_id string
,model_name string
,hardware_net string
,ip_address string
,country string
,region string
,city string
,os_type string
,os_architecture string
,os_locale string
,os_timezone string
,product_name string
,product_version string
,product_tier string
,participant_role string
,timezone string
,joinstart_ev_timestamp timestamp
,joinLaunch_ev_timestamp timestamp
,joinSession_ev_timestamp timestamp
,joinTime_ev_timestamp timestamp
,audioConnect_ev_timestamp timestamp
,connection_type string
,download_start_timestamp timestamp
,download_end_timestamp timestamp
,install_start_timestamp timestamp
,install_end_timestamp timestamp
,password_start_timestamp timestamp
,password_end_timestamp timestamp
,login_start_timestamp timestamp
,login_end_timestamp timestamp
,audioWait_start_timestamp timestamp
,audioWait_end_timestamp timestamp
,hallway_start_timestamp timestamp
,hallway_end_timestamp timestamp
,entrypoint_access_time double
,endpoint_access_time double
,panel_connect_time double
,audio_connect_time double
,install_time_endpoint double
,download_time_endpoint double
,install_time_launcher double
,download_time_launcher double
,join_time double
,process_data_timestamp timestamp
,source_date timestamp
,version string
,event_date timestamp
)
PARTITIONED BY (data_input_date string) 
stored as orc
location '${hiveconf:s3bucket}/${hiveconf:fact_path}/${hiveconf:join_session_fact}/'
TBLPROPERTIES (“orc.compress”=“snappy”);
```

NOTE THAT WHEN I AM RUNNING BELOW QUERY IN PRESTO THEN IT IS WORKING FINE:

```
select 
distinct cast(joinstart_ev_timestamp as date) as session_date, 
approx_percentile(cast(join_time as double),0.50) over (partition by 
cast(joinstart_ev_timestamp as date)) /1000 as jt,
product_name as product,
endpoint as endpoint
from datawarehouse.join_session_fact
where  
cast(joinstart_ev_timestamp as date)  between date '2018-01-18' and date '2018-01-30'
and lower(product_name) LIKE 'gotowebinar%' 
and join_time > 0 and join_time <= 600000 and join_time is not null 
and audio_connect_time >= 0 
and (entrypoint_access_time >= 0 or entrypoint_access_time is null)
and (panel_connect_time >= 0  or panel_connect_time is null) and version = 'V2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the correct conversion to Presto:

```
SELECT session_date,'min' as stats,mini as value,product,endpoint
from 
(select 
distinct cast(joinstart_ev_timestamp as date) as session_date, 
approx_percentile(cast(join_time as double),0.02) over (partition by 
cast(joinstart_ev_timestamp as date))/1000 as mini,
approx_percentile(cast(join_time as double),0.25) over (partition by 
cast(joinstart_ev_timestamp as date))/1000 as first_quartile,
approx_percentile(cast(join_time as double),0.50) over (partition by 
cast(joinstart_ev_timestamp as date))/1000 as jt,
approx_percentile(cast(join_time as double),0.75) over (partition by 
cast(joinstart_ev_timestamp as date))/1000 as third_quartile,
approx_percentile(cast(join_time as double),0.98) over (partition by 
cast(joinstart_ev_timestamp as date))/1000 as maxi,
product_name as product,
endpoint as endpoint
from datawarehouse.join_session_fact
where  
cast(joinstart_ev_timestamp as date)  between date_add('day', -16, now()) 
and  date_add('day', -1, now())
 and lower(product_name) LIKE 'gotowebinar%' 
 and join_time>0 and join_time <= 600000 and join_time is not null 
 and audio_connect_time >= 0  
and (entrypoint_access_time >= 0 or entrypoint_access_time is null)
and (panel_connect_time >= 0  or panel_connect_time is null) and version = 'V2')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the WITHIN GROUP. AFAIK, those percentile functions are not supported. The error is likely due to the grammar not recognizing the WITHIN GROUP() clause.

Comment: Hey Matt, that you for your reply.. I have updated the above question with the Query which is working fine.

Now, can you please help me out with finding the corresponding Presto syntax of the below Redshift query part: 

"  PERCENTILE_DISC(0.02) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cast(join_time as double)) over(partition by cast(joinstart_ev_timestamp as date))/1000 as mini   "